# Getting Undefined for this Javascript Function and Not Sure why

Tags: javascript

Okay. So, I'm quite a newbie to JS, but not to programming in general. I've written a little bit of a recursive function (don't mind the logic here), that works perfectly in Python but returns `undefined` in JavaScript. This may totally be a noob thing here, but I can't really find the source of this issue, especially as it works fine in Python.

I had initially thought it was a control flow issue but I wrote other control flow functions that worked fine. Also, right before the final return statement, I console.log the array and the values are returned. Any help will be appreciated

```js
path = []
let find_multiplier = (numb) => {
  if (numb === 1) {
    console.log("a result is possible for this number");
    console.log(path)
    return path;
  } else if (numb > 1) {
    if (numb % 3 === 0) {
      path.push("multiply by 3");
      find_multiplier(numb / 3);
    } else {
      path.push("add 5");
      find_multiplier(numb - 5);
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

console.log(find_multiplier(13)); // returns undefined. should return values.
console.log(find_multiplier(15)); // returns undefined. should return false.
```

Comment: `var path = [];`

Comment: There are four code paths but only two of them return something

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Globals are bad, but adding `var` in that place doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Andreas it won't throw anymore in strict-mode, which is a big improvement imho.

Comment: yes I know it's not resolutive... it was just a suggestion to begin with. You should always declare the variables correctly and since it was there out of nothing, var was the best assumption to me. If I wanted to make an answer, my contribution wouldn't be here as a comment

Comment: @ASDFGerte _"...doesn't change anything **in this particular case/question**"_ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that 2 of your 4 conditions does not return anything.

You can fix this by adding the `return` keyword in front of your recursive call.

```js
path = []
let find_multiplier = (numb) => {
  if (numb === 1) {
    console.log("a result is possible for this number");
    console.log(path)
    return path;
  } else if (numb > 1) {
    if (numb % 3 === 0) {
      path.push("multiply by 3");
      return find_multiplier(numb / 3); //here
    } else {
      path.push("add 5");
      return find_multiplier(numb - 5); //here
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

console.log(find_multiplier(13)); // returns undefined. should return values.
console.log(find_multiplier(15)); // returns undefined. should return false.
```

Comment: Oh right. Well, that was very silly of me, especially since the returns were in my Python solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe two of your cases are missing `return` statements:

```js
if (numb % 3 === 0){
    path.push("multiply by 3");
    return find_multiplier(numb / 3); // <-- add return here
} else {
    path.push("add 5");
    return find_multiplier(numb  - 5); // <-- and here
}
```

However, you are also mutating a variable (`path`) outside of the scope of your function, so I would guess even they way you have it currently, `path` may actually contain the result you're looking for. I would choose to either mutate the out-of-scope `path` array and not try to also return it, or declare the variable in your function and return that, with a preference to the latter.